# Viewpager fragment doesn't running functionally

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewpagerindicator

I am now trying to implement viewpager with fragment. Everything is cool except i got error **ViewPager has not been bound.
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log** in xml graphical layout.

And Here's a screenshot of my application.
[image: ViewPager]

Does anyone know why there is not showing indicator line below title ?

Comment: Please write the exception log...

Comment: @Warpzit I just see this error at xml graphical layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this project by referring this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator.
Go through that sample project. It will really helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: Actually i can implement the viewpager successfully. I just can't get the tab indicator line below Title even though i just copied the source code from work fine project.

Answer (score 1):

For the records, hope it saves someone some time:

- The Indicator needs to be bound to the ViewPager, something like `indicator.setViewPager(viewpager)`
- Without a theme, the ViewPagerIndicator will not work. If you don't want to use the default style, set the ViewPagerIndicator style only as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873396/default-style-fails-for-viewpagerindicators-tabpageindicator-why-and-how-to-fi#12074605)

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved by myself. All i need is just to add theme style android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults" in project manifest file.